# RGB function in react

Tags: react-native

I've recently started to work on React Native. I'm trying to create a simple function for generating Random Colors. The problem I am facing is that my IDE says that the variables that I have declared are not in use. Hence, the color is not generated on the my device's screen. Can anyone kindly have a look at it tell me what am I doing wrong?

P.S: I tried setting the color manually in the "View state" by writing "backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,255,0)'}}/>" and it successfully worked. The only time I am facing a problem is when I am trying to use the randomRGB function.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Button, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const ColorScreen = () => {
   return(
<View style={{height:100 ,  width:100, backgroundColor:randomRgb()}}/>
   }
const randomRgb = () =>{
    const red = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    const green = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    const blue = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

    return 'rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})';
};

export default ColorScreen;
```

Comment: Are you using backticks in your `randomRgb` function, or single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Nvm guys. I'm an idiot. I was using quote instead of backquotes. Yeah stupid I know, but I wouldn't delete this because there may be other people like me. So, use "  ` " instead.